# BizTalk 2020 SFTP Receive adapter not deleting files after downloading from MoveIT SFTP servers

Tags: sftp, deleting, biztalk

The issue is the BizTalk 2020 SFTP receive adapter does not delete the SFTP file after downloading it from a MoveIT SFTP server.

This issue has already been reported but I cannot find any resolution on-line yet:

https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29529

Apparently it's an issue with different timestamps being returned from the stat and ls commands from MoveIT SFTP servers:

https://community.progress.com/s/question/0D54Q00007uR3uASAS/ls-and-stat-commands-return-different-timestamps

I am thinking of writing some C# code to manually delete the file as a temporary work around.

However, I would like to know if there are any plans to fix this issue in a future BizTalk Cumulative Update?

Comment: Perhaps you should try asking the vendor directly.

Comment: I am in the process of logging a call with Microsoft directly but was hoping to get a quick answer on here.